# PHP form - only need to fill out an input if an option is selected

Tags: php, html

In the following form the user is asked to input a series of results from a scientific test of cream.
However I wanted it so that the user will only need to fill out the 'phos' box if the cream is earlier inputted as a tank or plant in the 'type' box.
How would I go about doing this?

```
<div class="jumbotron loginandcreateuser">
  <form method="post" action="cream.php">
    <table>
      <tr><th>Time</th><td><input type="time" name="cream_time"></td></tr>
      <tr><th>Provenance</th><td>
        <select name="prov">
          <option value="org">Org</option>
          <option value="conv">Conv</option>
        </select>
      </td></tr>
      <tr><th>Size</th><td><input type="text" name="size"></td></tr>
      <tr><th>Type</th><td>
        <select name="type">
          <option value="tank">tank</option>
          <option value="plant">plant</option>
          <option value="product">product</option>
        </select>
      </td></tr>
      <tr><th>Grade</th><td>
        <select name="grade">
          <option value="DC">DC</option>
          <option value="SC">SC</option>
          <option value="WC">WC</option>
        </select>
      </td></tr>
      <tr><th>Customer</th><td><input type="text" name="customer"></td></tr>
      <tr><th>Usebydate</th><td><input type="date" name="usebydate"></td></tr>
      <tr><th>Temp</th><td><input type="number" name="temp"></td></tr>
      <tr><th>B/fat</th><td><input type="number" name="b_fat"></td></tr>
      <tr><th>Phos</th><td><input type="number" name="phos"></td></tr>
    </table>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do this with pure PHP as it's a server side language. You would need to use JavaScript or jQuery to listen to that input and change the element with the client side language. Unless you split the form into two forms submit the first to the second and check the value there

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved with some javascript validation... below I am getting the value and adding an event listener so that a function is triggered when an options is selected.

That function checks to see if the selected option is tank or plant... if it is then we show the phos field, if not we hide the phos field.

```
<div class="jumbotron loginandcreateuser">
  <form method="post" action="cream.php">
    <table>
      <tr><th>Time</th><td><input type="time" name="cream_time"></td></tr>
      <tr><th>Provenance</th><td>
        <select name="prov">
          <option value="org">Org</option>
          <option value="conv">Conv</option>
        </select>
      </td></tr>
      <tr><th>Size</th><td><input type="text" name="size"></td></tr>
      <tr><th>Type</th><td>
        <select id="type" name="type">
          <option value="tank">tank</option>
          <option value="plant">plant</option>
          <option value="product">product</option>
        </select>
      </td></tr>
      <tr><th>Grade</th><td>
        <select name="grade">
          <option value="DC">DC</option>
          <option value="SC">SC</option>
          <option value="WC">WC</option>
        </select>
      </td></tr>
      <tr><th>Customer</th><td><input type="text" name="customer"></td></tr>
      <tr><th>Usebydate</th><td><input type="date" name="usebydate"></td></tr>
      <tr><th>Temp</th><td><input type="number" name="temp"></td></tr>
      <tr><th>B/fat</th><td><input type="number" name="b_fat"></td></tr>
      <tr id="phos" style="display: none"><th>Phos</th><td><input type="number" name="phos"></td></tr>
    </table>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br>
</div>

<script>

    document.getElementById("type").addEventListener("change", enablePhosTextarea);

    function enablePhosTextarea() {
        type = document.getElementById("type");
        value = type.value;
        if (value === 'tank' || value === 'plant') {
            document.getElementById("phos").removeAttribute("style", "display: none;");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("phos").setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Try it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/f34184u1/

Answer (score 0):

None of your form controls are currently set to required, so as it is now, your user already doesn't have to fill in the phos input, regardless of which type is selected.

As far as client-side interaction, there are various different ways you can use JavaScript to conditionally set a control to be required (or visible, as suggested in the other answer) depending on the value of another control.

This can be helpful to provide a better user experience, but regardless of what you decide to do on the client side, *you must validate the input on the server side*. Client-side validation can easily be bypassed, either intentionally and unintentionally, so you need to verify that you have appropriate input in the part of your application where it will actually be used.

Here's a really basic example of how you could do this in `cream.php`:

```
session_start();              // start the session so you can store potential errors
unset($_SESSION['errors']);   // clear any errors from previous attempts

// Check for invalid input
if (in_array($_POST['type'], ['tank', 'plant']) && $_POST['phos'] = '') {

    // store an error in the session
    $_SESSION['errors']['phos'] = 'You must enter a value for Phos for tank/plant types.';

    // redirect back to your input form
    header('Location: path/to/yourinputform.php');
    exit();
}

// If no input validation errors are encountered, then go ahead with
// however you're normally processing the input data.
```

Then in your login form, check the session for errors, and display them in the appropriate locations if there are any. There's more to it than this, but this should give you the general idea.

Many of the various PHP frameworks out there (Laravel, Symfony, etc.) have built-in methods for this type of thing that simplify this and take care of the various gotchas you may encounter if you do this yourself.

Answer (score -2):

you will need to use Javascript for that

Comment: I think this is a comment